# mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop

Tags: generics, vector, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Rust newbie here, I've looked for similar cases in StackOverflow (and there are quite a few), but they all had slightly different scenarios, and I couldn't figure out a way to fix this.

I'm trying to loop over some strings, pass them to a function that applies some operation on them and eventually push the result into a vector. (the actual case is too complex for a `map` scenario).

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=033a7cbf66a7a047d1fbdfd182df9bad)

```rust
mod lifetime_test {
    fn parse_line<'a>(item: &'a str, target: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>) {
        // ... use item to compute a result
        target.push("result");
    }

    fn parse_file() {
        let mut target: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
        let source: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

        // ... fill source with strings from file

        for item in source {
            parse_line(item, &mut target);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The above doesn't compile: `mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop` at the `parse_line` call.

I think I understand why it complains about the multiple mutable borrows, but I cannot find a way to pass the string and the vector, and have the `parse_line` function store its results into the passed vector.

In the actual case the `parse_line` function is complex and it might or might not add values to a couple of vectors so I think making `parse_line` return the multiple values would make it more complex to understand. So I'd rather pass the vector(2) and have `parse_line` decide if it needs or no adding a new value to it.

Comment: The code in the playground link does not seem related to your question at all. Did you use the correct link? If not can you please update it?

Comment: edited the link to the playground. I've also discovered that if I use `String` instead of `&str` it does not complain. So I don't really understand how this works. I'll re-read the relevant parts of the Book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```rust
fn parse_line<'a>(item: &'a str, target: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>)
```

To:

```rust
fn parse_line<'a>(item: &'a str, target: &mut Vec<&'a str>)
```

Just because you have a function which is generic over some lifetime `'a` that doesn't mean that literally every reference used by the function must have the `'a` lifetime. The lifetime of the mutable borrow of `target` must be shorter than or equal to `'a`, but you don't want it to be equal because it would heavily restrict your code (and is just plain unnecessary), so as long as you remove the `'a` annotation from mutable borrow of `target` the compiler infers the appropriate lifetime for the mutable borrow and the code compiles:

```rust
fn parse_line<'a>(item: &'a str, target: &mut Vec<&'a str>) {
    // ... use item to compute a result
    target.push("result");
}

fn parse_file() {
    let mut target: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    let source: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

    // ... fill source with strings from file

    for item in source {
        parse_line(item, &mut target);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=b6665a3a3e17f0cd1b9fdac1c1d4cd55)

Comment: ok, thank you so much. That makes sense. So, if I can put it in my own words, the previous error came because I was forcing `item` and `&mut target` to have the same lifetime, but that was wrong because `item` lives only inside the loop, while `&mut target` is also outside the loop? why would it complain with `cannot borrow `target` as mutable more than once at a time`? There's still something I don't get.

Comment: @user103716 Yes, I believe that's correct. I can't say for certain without seeing your full code but in a nutshell: you were forcing the compiler to figure out some lifetime `'a` that would work for both `&mut target` and `item` but that's an unnecessary burdensome requirement since the lifetime of those variables does not actually have to be the same.

Comment: @user103716 you were telling rustc that `target` would be borrowed for the entirety of its contents. Since the contents necessarily have to outlive the container, that means the lifetime `'a` exceeds the life of the container, so rustc inferred the only possible solution for your requirements: consider the `target` mutably borrowed until it is dropped. This means the borrow from the first iteration would overlap with every following borrow, and since mutable borrows are exclusive that's not acceptable.